# Grep for lines not beginning with "//"

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I'm trying but failing to write a regex to grep for lines that do not begin with "//" (i.e. C++-style comments). I'm aware of the "grep -v" option, but I am trying to learn how to pull this off with regex alone.
I've searched and found various answers on grepping for lines that don't begin with a character, and even one on how to grep for lines that don't begin with a string, but I'm unable to adapt those answers to my case, and I don't understand what my error is.

```
> cat bar.txt
hello
//world
> cat bar.txt | grep "(?!\/\/)"
-bash: !\/\/: event not found
```

I'm not sure what this "event not found" is about. One of the answers I found used paren-question mark-exclamation-string-paren, which I've done here, and which still fails.

```
> cat bar.txt | grep "^[^\/\/].+"
(no output)
```

Another answer I found used a caret within square brackets and explained that this syntax meant "search for the absence of what's in the square brackets (other than the caret). I think the ".+" means "one or more of anything", but I'm not sure if that's correct and if it is correct, what distinguishes it from ".*"

In a nutshell: how can I construct a regex to pass to grep to search for lines that do not begin with "//" ?

To be even more specific, I'm trying to search for lines that have "#include" that are not preceeded by "//".

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line tells you that the problem is from `bash` (your shell). Bash finds the `!` and attempts to inject into your command the last you entered that begins with `\/\/`. To avoid this you need to escape the `!` or use single quotes. For an example of `!`, try `!cat`, it will execute the last command beginning with `cat` that you entered.

You don't need to escape `/`, it has no special meaning in regular expressions. You also don't need to write a complicated regular expression to invert a match. Rather, just supply the `-v` argument to grep. Most of the time simple is better. And you also don't need to cat the file to grep. Just give grep the file name. eg.

```
grep -v "^//" bar.txt | grep "#include"
```

If you're really hungup on using regular expressions then a simple one would look like (match start of string `^`, any number of white space `[[:space:]]*`, exactly two backslashes `/{2}`, any number of any characters `.*`, followed by `#include`):

```
grep -E "^[[:space:]]*/{2}.*#include" bar.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You're using negative lookahead which is PCRE feature and requires `-P` option
2. Your negative lookahead won't work without start anchor
3. This will of course require `gnu-grep`.
4. You must use single quotes to use `!` in your regex otherwise history expansion is attempted with the text after `!` in your regex, the reason of `!\/\/: event not found` error.

So you can use:

```
grep -P '^(?!\h*//)' file
hello
```

`\h` matches 0 or more horizontal whitespace.

Without `-P` or non-gnu grep you can use `grep -v`:

```
grep -v '^[[:blank:]]*//' file
hello
```

Answer (score 2):

To find `#include` lines that are not preceded by `//` (or `/*` …), you can use:

```
grep '^[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*include[[:space:]]*["<]'
```

The regex looks for start of line, optional spaces, `#`, optional spaces, `include`, optional spaces and either `"` or `<`.  It will find all `#include` lines except lines such as `#include MACRO_NAME`, which are legitimate but rare, and screwball cases such as:

```
#/*comment*/include/*comment*/<stdio.h>
#\
include\
<stdio.h>
```

If you have to deal with software containing such notations, (a) you have my sympathy and (b) fix the code to a more orthodox style before hunting the `#include` lines.  It will pick up false positives such as:

```
/* Do not include this:
#include <does-not-exist.h>
*/
```

You could omit the final `[[:space:]]*["<]` with minimal chance of confusion, which will then pick up the macro name variant.

---

To find lines that do not start with a double slash, use `-v` (to invert the match) and `'^//'` to look for slashes at the start of a line:

```
grep -v '^//'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `-P` (perl) option:

```
cat bar.txt | grep -P '(?!//)'
```

Answer (score 0):

For the lines not beginning with "//", you could use `(^[^/]{2}.*$)`.

Comment: That would not find a line that contains just 1 or 0 characters and appending `.*$` adds no value to any regexp, nor do the parens.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like `grep -v` for this then you could just use awk:

```
awk '!/^\/\//' file
```

Since awk supports compound conditions instead of just regexps, it's often easier to specify what you want to match with awk than grep, e.g. to search for `a` and `b` in any order with grep:

```
grep -E 'a.*b|b.*a`
```

while with awk:

```
awk '/a/ && /b/'
```